# Formatting a Alphabetized Collection

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

i have a Collection for lastnames read in from an employee class.  Is it possible to Organize the output of the sorted names after the Sort?  I need an output that is similar to the line i have commented out, instead of the generic single line output with lastnames seperated by comma "[Name1, Name2, Name3...]" which i get now from the Collection...

```
 public void alpha1()
    {
     LinkedList<String> alphalist = new LinkedList<String>();
     ListIterator<Employee> iterate = list.listIterator(0);
    // System.out.println("First Name" + "\t" + "Last Name" + "\t" + "Salary");
     while (iterate.hasNext())
      {
           emp = iterate.next();

       alphalist.add(emp.getlastname());
      }
      Collections.sort(alphalist, new Comparator<String>() {
         @Override
         public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
             return Collator.getInstance().compare(o1, o2);
         }
     });
     System.out.println(alphalist);
    }
```

Comment: or is it possible to insert more than one value into a collection.  For instance can i insert the First Name, Last Name, and Salary into the collection, and then have it sort by Last name, but organize the First name and salary alongside the sorted Last Name appropriately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think better to create `Comparator` on `Employee` object and sort the original collection itself.

Once your collection is sorted, iterate and print your collection using `Employee` object itself.

e.g.

```
 public void alpha1()
   {
       Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Employee>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
          return o1.getLastName().compareTo(o2.getLastName());
        }
      });

      ListIterator<Employee> iterate = list.listIterator();
      while (iterate.hasNext())
      {
        emp = iterate.next();
        System.out.println("First Name" + "\t" + "Last Name" + "\t" + "Salary");
      }
    }
```

Comment: i am trying this method. i will let you know how it goes promptly

Comment: @user1660948: Sure. Let me know, if doesn't work.

Comment: what would the output call look like.  i tried "System.out.println(list)" however that just gives junk memory address type output. e.g : "Employee@683267dd"

Comment: @user1660948 I am already mentioned the printing.  `ListIterator<Employee> iterate = list.listIterator();
      while (iterate.hasNext())
      {
        emp = iterate.next();
        System.out.println("First Name" + "\t" + "Last Name" + "\t" + "Salary");
      }` prints your sorted employees name.

Comment: @user1660948: Since its list of `Employee` hence you need to iterate the list and print the fields or override `toString()` method in your `Employee` class.

Comment: ok thanks. i will close the question when i get this implemented

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing a list of last name strings, the better approach would be to store employee objects and sort them by their last name.

You can implement `Comparable` in your `Employee` class to define its natural sorting.  Then, you make `alphalist` a list of employees, and sort it using `Collections.sort(alphalist)`.

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {
    ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee emp) {
        return this.getLastName().compareTo(emp.getLastName());
    }
}
```

Then, your new `alpha1()` method:

```
public void alpha1() {
    LinkedList<Employee> alphalist = new LinkedList<Employee>();
    ListIterator<Employee> iterate = list.listIterator(0);
    while (iterate.hasNext()) {
        alphalist.add(iterate.next());
    }
    Collections.sort(alphalist);
    System.out.println(alphalist); 
}
```

Comment: i attempted this method. but i got an error with the Comparable implementation of Employee

Comment: @user1660948 My bad, the method should have been `compareTo` instead of `compare`. I've fixed it.

Comment: the error i am getting is "type Comparable does not take parameters"

Comment: Make sure you're using the correct [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).